# Mocking Direct3D API calls

Tags: c++, api, pointers, googletest, googlemock

I am trying to convert raw pointers to smart pointers and at the same time create unit tests for classes that call a lot of Windows API.

In a case like this, how do I convert them to smart pointers? And is it possible to mock them?  Here is the current code:

```
CComPtrCustom<IDirect3D9> d3d;
d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, NULL, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &parameters, &device);
```

So far I only have:

```
std::unique_ptr<CComPtrCustom<IDirect3D9>> d3d; // This is on the .h file
d3d = std::make_unique<CComPtrCustom<IDirect3D9>>(Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION));
```

But I do not know how to call

```
d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, NULL, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &parameters, &device);
```

And mock them.

So how to mock and is my code above correct? Help!

Comment: I know what CComPtr is, but I've never heard of **CComPtrCustom**?  What is that?

Comment: Honestly, I have a solid idea on how to do this... but I gotta put the kids to be and it would take a while to write up.  Bottom line: Go get [Google Test](https://github.com/google/googletest) to do the mocks, and then do a MOCK_METHOD on CreateDevice to return another mock of an IDirect3DDevice9 instance.  Also,  I wouldn't mix CComPtr and unique_ptr.

Comment: "Also, I wouldn't mix CComPtr and unique_ptr" -- can you elaborate? Thanks!!!

Comment: CComPtr is already a smart pointer class.  A unique_ptr to a CComPtr as you have it declared above is just weird and will lead to bugs and refcount issues.